# Explode a nested array into new columns using Java Spark

Tags: java, arrays, apache-spark

I have a nested array in which I want to take all the elements in and put them each into a new column. This is what I have so far. Tried writing 2 methods but neither worked. Current error I'm getting from the uncommented code is

> `cannot resolve 'split(response.indicator, ',')' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires string type, however, 'response.indicator' is of array<struct<_VALUE:string,_number:bigint>> type.;;`

```
File.withColumn("response.indicator", explode(col("response.ind")))
            .withColumn("response.indicator", split(col("response.indicator"), ","))
            .withColumn("key", col("response.indicator").getItem(1))
            .withColumn("value", col("response.indicator").getItem(0))
            .groupBy("ID")
            .pivot("key")
            .agg(first("value"))
            .show(true);

    /*File.select("response.indicator").collectAsList().forEach(row -> {
        String name = String.valueOf(row.getList(0).get(1));
        String value = String.valueOf(row.getList(0).get(0));
        File.withColumn(name, col(value));
    });*/
```

Here is the schema

```
 |-- ID: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- response: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- indicator: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _VALUE: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _number: long (nullable = true)
```

What my data looks like

```
+--------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|ID                  |response     
+--------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1                  |[WrappedArray([N,7], [N,8], [N,9], [N,19], [N,20], [N,22], [N,12], [N,1], [N,2], [N,3], [N,4], [N,5], [N,6], [N,10], [N,11], [N,13], [N,14], [N,15], [N,16], [N,17], [N,18], [N,21], [N,25], [N,26])]  |  
| 2                  |[WrappedArray([Y,1], [N,8], [N,9], [N,19], [N,22], [Y,22], [N,20], [Y,7], [Y,23], [N,3], [Y,4], [N,11], [N,6], [Y,27], [N,5], [N,13], [N,14], [N,15], [Y,16], [N,17], [Y,18], [N,21], [N,25], [N,26])]    |
+--------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

What I want it to look like

```
+--------------------+-----------------------------+
|ID                  | 1 | 2    | 3 |  etc 
+--------------------+-----------------------------+
| 1                  | N | N    | N | etc 
| 2                  | Y | NULL | N |  etc
+--------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is `split(col("response.indicator"), ",")` expects a string column whereas `response.indicator` actually is a `struct`. To "unfold" a `struct` named `s`, you can use `s.*` as follows:

```java
// I use the names provided in the schema, not the ones from your code.
File.withColumn("indicator", explode(col("response.indicator")))
    .select("ID", "indicator.*")
    .groupBy("ID")
    .pivot("_number")
    .agg(first("_value"))
    .show();
```

Comment: I didn't post a few other lines but I was trying to cast the long element into a string and a whole other mess to try to resolve the datatype mismatch error. But to think all I needed to do was a select statement. Thanks! Was struggling for a while on this.

Comment: Do you know how to modify the name of the pivot column? I want to just append a value to each one so each column looks like indicator_1, indicator_2, etc. Trying to collectasList and use a WithColumnRenamed but no luck.

Comment: Actually, found the solution. Added a .withColumn("modified_number", concat(lit("indicator_"), col("_number"))) in between the select and groupBy statement