# How to explode a nested array into new columns while also keeping the rest of the table intact in Java Spark

Tags: java, sql, apache-spark

Building upon a question I asked earlier [Explode a nested array into new columns using Java Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75658224/explode-a-nested-array-into-new-columns-using-java-spark)

Here is the schema

```
 |-- ID: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Name: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- response: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- status: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- indicator: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _VALUE: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _number: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- result: string (nullable = true)
```

Now what the answer in my previously asked question does ends up only having a table with the ID and now exploded indicator array. Status, name, result are gone. I have way more columns and also nested elements in that response column though so manually selecting each one isn't an option. I want to keep everything else as is, just explode the array into new columns. I'm trying different methods such as trying store the table with just the ID and array into a temporary table, dropping the nested array element from the original table and then joining the two on the ID column. I'm also trying to do a select on the entire response column and try to filter out the indicator element and store everything else while maintaining the original struct in a new table then drop that column from the original table then join the original, this single column table, and the exploded array table into one. I don't know what approach I should be taking or if I'm even going down the right path here.

Here is some test code I've written so far with no success. None of these lines are connected, just different approaches I've tried.

```
Dataset<Row> result = File.select("response.*").columns().filter(row -> row.equals(col("indicator"))).map(s -> col(s));

Dataset<Row> result = File.select("response.*")filter(c -> !c.equals(col("indicator")));

File.drop(col("response")).withColumn("response", struct(result));

File.drop("response).join(result, File.col(ID).equalTo(result.col(ID)), "outer");
```

What I want the schema to look like

```
|-- ID: integer (nullable = true)
|-- Name: integer (nullable = true)
|-- response: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- status: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- result: string (nullable = true)
|-- response_indicator_number: integer (nullable = true) <-- response.indicator._VALUE elements in this column
```

Answer (score 0):

So basically you want to:

- explode the dataframe based on the `response.indicator` array
- add a column `response_indicator_number=response.indicator._VALUE`
- remove the `indicator` field from the `response` structure.

For the latter, let's "simply" recreate the `response` struct with all its columns but `indicator`. We can do it generically by accessing the list of fields from the schema:

```py
# List of all columns but response
df_cols = list(filter(lambda x: x != 'response', df.columns))

# Extracting the response field from the schema
response_field = [f for f in df.schema.fields if f.name == 'response'][0]

# list of columns in the response struct, except indicator
response_cols = [ F.col('response.'+f.name).alias(f.name) 
                      for f in response_field.dataType.fields
                      if f.name != 'indicator']

# And finally:
result =  df\
    .withColumn("indicator", F.explode('response.indicator'))\
    .select(df_cols + [F.struct(response_cols).alias('response'),
            F.col('indicator._VALUE').alias('response_indicator_number')])

result.printSchema()
```

```
root
 |-- ID: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- Name: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- response: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- status: string (nullable = false)
 |    |-- result: string (nullable = false)
 |-- response_indicator_number: string (nullable = false)
```

And since the answer was in java, here is a java version

```java
// List of all columns but response
List<Column> df_cols = Arrays.stream(df.columns())
    .filter(x -> ! x.equals("response"))
    .map(functions::col)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

// Extracting the response field from the schema
StructField response_field = Arrays.stream(df.schema().fields())
    .filter(x -> x.name().equals("response"))
    .findAny().get();

// list of columns in the response struct, except indicator
List<Column> response_cols = Arrays
    .stream(((StructType) response_field.dataType()).fields())
    .filter(x -> ! x.name().equals("indicator"))
    .map(x -> functions.col("response."+x.name()).alias(x.name()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        
// Adding the new response struct and response_indicator_number to df_cols
df_cols.add(functions.struct(JavaConverters.asScalaBuffer(response_cols).toSeq()).alias("response"));
df_cols.add(functions.col("indicator._VALUE").alias("response_indicator_number"));

// And finally:
Dataset<Row> x =  df
    .withColumn("indicator", functions.explode(functions.col("response.indicator")))
    .select(JavaConverters.asScalaBuffer(df_cols).toSeq());
```

Comment: Ended up coming up with a solution the creates 3 tables all with the monotonically_increasing_id() column added. 1 table with the exploded indicator. 1 with just the nested response column without indicator. I did an explode, dropped indicator and then select(struct) to put it back into a nested state. Lastly the original table with the increasing_id column added then joined all three tables on the increasing_id column and then dropped it. However, I'm also interested in your solution. However, I can't seem to set it up in Java. I can't seem to do a .columns().filter() to get all but response

Comment: I am so used to people asking for python that I jumped into it without thinking about it. Sorry :$ Let me write it in java.

Comment: That should be it. I have not tested it so let me know if it does not work right away.

Comment: `No such struct field status in _VALUE, _number`  error came on `.select(JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(df_cols).toSeq());`. Also I changed it to JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer since it doesn't seem to exist under JavaConverters.

Comment: It's funny. I tested it and the exact same code works for me. Can you tell me what versions of spark, scala and java you are using?

Comment: java 8, spark 2

Answer (score 0):

OP here. Ended up coming with a solution. I don't think it's efficient but it works.

```
Dataset<Row> original_with_id = File.withColumn("original_joinID", monotonically_increasing_id());

Dataset<Row> nestedColumn = original_with_id.select("response.*")
                .drop("indicator")
                .select(struct("*").alias(response))
                .withColumn("nested_joinID", monotonically_increasing_id());

Dataset<Row> exploded_column = original_with_id.withColumn("pivotTransformationGroupBy", col("ID"))
                .withColumn("exploded", explode(col("response.indicator")))
                .select("pivotTransformationGroupBy", "exploded.*")
                .withColumn("renamed_pivotColumn", concat(lit("response_indicator_"), col("_number")))
                .groupBy("pivotTransformationGroupBy")
                .pivot("renamed_pivotColumn")
                .agg(first("_VALUE"));

Dataset<Row> result = original_with_id.drop("response")
                .join(nestedColumn, original_with_id.col("original_joinID").equalTo(nestedColumn.col("nested_joinID")))
                .join(exploded_column, original_with_id.col("ID").equalTo(exploded_column.col("pivotTransformationGroupBy")))
                .drop("pivotTransformationGroupBy", "original_joinID", "nested_joinID");
```